# Ajax progress bar until my success function is finished

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am implementing an ajax progress bar, I want the progress should not reach 100% until my ajax success function is finished.

```
    $.ajax({

        data: //data,
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 10;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 100) {
                   clearInterval(id);
                } 
                            else {
                   width++; 
                   elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                   elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';                               
                    }
                   }
         return xhr;
},
success: // code
        };
```

My ajax progress bar shows 100% , but still waits until the success function is finished. So, i am looking for that my progress bar should not reach 100% until my success function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, so it will be 100% only when done.

html

```
<progress></progress>
```

jQuery Code

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        //Form data
        data: new FormData($('#fileupload-form')[0]), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and values
        // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        // You *must* include these options!
        cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
        contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server. Default is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false (i.e. data should not be in the form of string)
        //Custom XMLHttpRequest
        xhr: function(){
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                // For handling the progress of the upload
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        $('progress').attr({
                            value: e.loaded,
                            max: e.total,
                        });
                    }
                } , false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(res){

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this. But it directly loads my loading bar from 10% to 100% in the ajax call. Even though my ajax call takes some time.